# return dictionary with nth value in all lists within a nested dictionary and retain other values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested, data-wrangling

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
dict_in = {'key0': {a: [A, B, C], b: [A, B, C]}, 'key1': {c: [A, B, C], d: [A, B, C]}, 'key2': {e: 0, f: 0}}
```

I want a function (or whatever) that returns the same dictionary but without the lists. In the place of the lists is a single value that corresponds to the nth value in each list. For keys that do not have a corresponding list I just want the value to remain the same. For example, some function as such:

```
nth_val = 2
def take_nth_value_from_lists_in_nested_dict(list_in, nth_val):
    ...things and stuff...
    return dict_out
```

```
dict_out = {'key0': {a: B, b: B}, 'key1': {c: B, d: B}, 'key2': {e: 0, f: 0}}
```

Note how key2 stayed the same. I have no idea how to do this elegantly so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What should happen if the list do not have n positions? Also are the list arbitrary nested?

Comment: @DaniMesejo good point. Ideally it would throw an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it with recursion:

```
def take_nth_value_from_lists_in_nested_dict(obj, n: int):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        return {k: take_nth_value_from_lists_in_nested_dict(v, n) for k, v in obj.items()}
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        return take_nth_value_from_lists_in_nested_dict(obj[n-1], n)
    return obj
```

```
>>> take_nth_value_from_lists_in_nested_dict({'a': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'b': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'key1': {'c': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'd': ['A', 'B', 'C']}, 'key2': {'e': 0, 'f': 0}}, 2)
{'a': 'B', 'b': 'B', 'key1': {'c': 'B', 'd': 'B'}, 'key2': {'e': 0, 'f': 0}}
```

This ought to work for arbitrarily deep nesting, including within list elements (e.g. if the Nth list element is itself a dict containing more dicts/lists).

Comment: Very impressive! In fact, your solution was so quick and impressive its has made me question my abilities and prospects as a coder :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could try with:

```
list_in = {'key0': {'a': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'b': ['A', 'B', 'C']}, 'key1': {'c': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'd': ['A', 'B', 'C']}, 'key2': {'e': 0, 'f': 0}}
nth = 1
for k,v in list_in.items():
    for k2 in v.keys():
        element = list_in[k][k2]
        if isinstance(element, list):
            list_in[k][k2] = element[nth]
print(list_in)
```

It returns:

```
{'key0': {'a': 'B', 'b': 'B'},
 'key1': {'c': 'B', 'd': 'B'},
 'key2': {'e': 0, 'f': 0}}
```

Comment: It is a dictionary with lists in it so you would have to loop through each key-value pair to an arbitrary depth. Your suggestion would only work on lists.

Comment: I proposed a little function for the list. I have updated my answer. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

A one-line solution might look like this:

```py
list_in = {'key0': {'a': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'b': ['A', 'B', 'C']}, 'key1': {'c': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'd': ['A', 'B', 'C']}, 'key2': {'e': 0, 'f': 0}}
nth = 1
list_out = {k: {k2: v2 if not isinstance(v2,list) else v2[nth] \
               for k2,v2 in v.items() } \
               for k,v in list_in.items() }

print list_out
```

```
{'key2': {'e': 0, 'f': 0}, 'key1': {'c': 'B', 'd': 'B'}, 'key0': {'a': 'B', 'b': 'B'}}
```

Note that I replaced keys and lists' values with strings.

Comment: Thanks! Impressed you could get this in one line. Although, I like @Samwise 's approach a bit more.

Comment: Yep, this solution only works  for this specific case. Samwise's will work for the general case.

Answer (score 0):

as I understand you correctly, you would like to read out the n-th element of a list in a nested dictionary and therefore require a function that will do that.

The way I've solved this task is recursively but before we'll dive into the way the function works, let's first try to understand what we can do with a dictionary. Below are four useful methods when working with a dictionary:

**.keys()
.values()
.items()
.update()**

```
test_dict = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}

# Read out keys
list(test_dict.keys())
>>> ['a', 'b', 'c']

# Read out values
list(test_dict.values())
>>> [1, 2, 3]

# Read out keys and values together
list(test_dict.items())
>>> [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]

# Update a dictionary with a new key, value pair or overwrite an existing one
test_dict.update({'d':4})
test_dict
>>> {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
```

Notice what we get with the method **.items()**:
A list with the key, value pairs as tuples

```
# I'm a tuple
('something','something else','etc.')
```

We can make use of the property that a list is iterable with a for-loop and that's exactly what we need at the beginning of the function. So let us begin to code:

```
def nth_element_from_list_in_nested_dict(nested_dict, list_index):
    # Iterate trough a list with tuples
    for key,val in nested_dict.items():
```

The variables key, val represent now the entries of the individual tuples:
From our *test_dict* this would be:

```
# On the first iteration
key='a'
val=1

# On the second iteration
key='b'
val=2

# and so on...
```

Since we assume that the dictionary passed to the function is nested, we therefore want to check if variable **val** is another dictionary. This can be done in an if-Statement:

```
def nth_element_from_list_in_nested_dict(nested_dict, list_index):
    # Iterate trough a list with tuples
    for key,val in nested_dict.items():
    # Check if variable val is another dictionary
    if isinstance(val, dict): 
    # isinstance(val, type: for example dict or list) returns True if val is of specified type
```

Now comes the recursive part of the function. As long as the value of a passed dictionary to the function is another dictionary, we call the function within the function again until the value is of another type (like a list!). Because when we have a list as value, we don't need to ,dig' deeper because we have reached the value from where we can select the n-th element from. Hope this still makes sense... Let's progress with the code:

```
def nth_element_from_list_in_nested_dict(nested_dict, list_index):
    # Iterate trough a list with tuples
    for key,val in nested_dict.items():
    # Check if variable val is another dictionary
    if isinstance(val, dict):
        nth_element_from_list_in_nested_dict(val, list_index) # calls the function again when val is another dictionary
    elif isinstance(val, list):
```

When we have found a value that is a list, we can now update this dictionary with the n-th element from that list:

```
def nth_element_from_list_in_nested_dict(nested_dict, list_index):
    # Iterate trough a list with tuples
    for key,val in nested_dict.items():
    # Check if variable val is another dictionary
    if isinstance(val, dict):
        nth_element_from_list_in_nested_dict(val, list_index) # calls the function again when val is another dictionary
    elif isinstance(val, list):
        nested_dict.update({key:val[list_index]}) # updates dictionary with the n-th element from val (when val is of type list)
```

All we have to do now is returning the updated dictionary and see if the function really does what is intended with your example dictionary (I've replaced your variables in *list_in* with strings since they haven't been defined)

```
### Input ###
list_in = {'key0': 
           {'a': ['A','B', 'C'], 
            'b': ['A', 'B', 'C']
           }, 
           'key1': 
           {'c': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 
            'd': ['A', 'B', 'C']
           }, 
           'key2': {
               'e': 0, 
               'f': 0,
           }
          }

### Function ###   
def nth_element_from_list_in_nested_dict(nested_dict, list_index):
    #
    for key,val in nested_dict.items():
        if isinstance(val, dict):
            nth_element_from_list_in_nested_dict(val, list_index)
        elif isinstance(val, list):
            nested_dict.update({key:val[list_index]})
    return nested_dict

### Tests ###   
# replace with first element (list_index=0)
to_be_updated = list_in.copy()
nth_element_from_list_in_nested_dict(to_be_updated, 0)
>>> {'key0': {'a': 'A', 'b': 'A'},
     'key1': {'c': 'A', 'd': 'A'},
     'key2': {'e': 0, 'f': 0}}

# replace with third element (list_index=2)
to_be_updated = list_in.copy()
nth_element_from_list_in_nested_dict(to_be_updated, 2)
>>> {'key0': {'a': 'C', 'b': 'C'},
     'key1': {'c': 'C', 'd': 'C'},
     'key2': {'e': 0, 'f': 0}}
```

It turned out to be a quite long explanation and maybe some parts (like the recursive part in the function) is difficult to understand. Further is this function prone to errors when the lists are of different lengths.
Nonetheless, I hope this can help you and others getting forward ;)